# GPS LocationListener and phone sleeping

Tags: android, gps

I've created service which has LocationListener in it. In order to keep service running the service is set as foreground. I have some questions about phone power management and sleeping in that circumstances:

1. Will phone go to sleep while such service is running?
2. How can I save power in this stuation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the service to sleep then you can keep the device awake.

Snippet:

```
private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock; //member variable
```

somewhere in your service class:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "some_tag");
```

When you're done running then you can do:

```
wakeLock.release();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Will phone go to sleep while such service is running?

Yes.

Answer (score 0):

How about a background Service that periodically gets launched using [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) and goes back to sleep after persisting coordinates to a database or file?